Prerequisites to organic chem
I want to study organic chem from the book "Advanced organic chemistry" by Francis A. Carey and Richard J. Sundberg. I am asking about prerequisites for studying this specific book. If no prerequisites are required except for basic chemistry, I will assume it's self-conttained.

Well, if it's "Advanced' then logic says you should already know organic chemistry pretty well. If well enough should be quickly verified upon lecture.
